# GDB 8.2 macOS High Sierra - program stops immediately after 'run'

Tags: macos, gcc, gdb

I finally managed to run GDB 8.2 on macOS. But now when I'm trying to debug something, I got the following:

```
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x100001e94: file project/src/main.cpp, line 34.
(gdb) run
Starting program: project/cmake-build-debug/program
[New Thread 0x1203 of process 5140]
[New Thread 0xf03 of process 5140]

[5]+  Stopped                 sudo gdb beast
```

I also tried using it inside CLion. In that case, GDB freezes indefinitely with this:

```
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
Function "__cxx_global_var_init" not defined.
Function "__libc_csu_init" not defined.
[New Thread 0x1003 of process 4186]
[New Thread 0xf03 of process 4186]
Warning:
Cannot insert breakpoint -1.
Cannot access memory at address 0xf7ce
```

Does anybody know what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [5]+  Stopped                 sudo gdb beast

This is a gdb bug.  The typical cause of this is gdb trying to write something to stdout after it has already given the terminal to the inferior.  I'm not sure whether this instance has been fixed, probably because this is most likely only showing up due to:

> ```
> Warning:
> Cannot insert breakpoint -1.
> Cannot access memory at address 0xf7ce
> ```

... this.  This is [another bug](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=20981) in gdb, namely that it wasn't updated to account for dyld changes in High Sierra.  This bug is fixed and will be in gdb 8.3 (or in any rate in the release after 8.2.1, regardless of what number it is finally given).

Building a gdb from git master will work fine.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If only it compiled with my gcc though... I'll try to build it as you suggest, and if it works - it works.

Comment: Yeah, it works with CLion at least, thank you. Can't use it directly, though, but the problem might lie in my lack of experience with gdb.